# Unable to switch back to parent window from child window which is closed automatically

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver, window

I have problems when switching between two windows. *The scenario looks like that:
I open the  landing page of the application, then I click on login link, a pop-up window opens, I type the credentials then I click on login button (here the pop-up is automatically closed). After that I have to come back to original window, and proceed with other actions, since I have logged-in into the application.*
The problem is that, it happens very often that I am not able to switch back to parent window, after pop-up is automatically closed, and the webdriver it just hanging, without doing anything, no error is thrown.

I have tried all kind of solutions found on google, but nothing really worked all the time. 
Last piece of code that I tried is the one below:

```
getLandingPageObject().performClickOnEmailLink();
getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
            // iterate through your windows
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String parent = it.next();
                String newwin = it.next();
                getDriver().switchTo().window(newwin);
                typeLoginCredentials(username, password);
                performClickOnLoginButton();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                getDriver().switchTo().window(parent);
            }
        }
 loginShouldBeSuccessful();
```

**I use Firefox 47.0.1 and Selenium 2.53.1**

Any idea how could I fix this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Check if you are not switched automatically or see if window method can be called without any parameter.

Comment: I doesn't switch automatically and I need to use parameters for window method to type different credentials in order to login into the application.The piece of code that I posted above works but not all time (sometimes the main window is hanging without doing anything, after pop-up is closed), I can't understand why.

Comment: @Larisa, try driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent() after the action which is causing pop up close automatically.

Comment: @SandipanPramanik is not working with driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent(). The thing is that after pop-up is closed automatically, the main window loads a new URL, different than the one that was before clicking the button which prompts out the pop-up window. This has something to do with it?

Comment: Another thing would be that my test is parametrized to run with 4 different type of accounts, this means 4 browser instances starts at the same time on my local machine. Could this be a problem when switching between windows?

Comment: @Larisa, when we use Set to get all available window handles, we might not getting handles sequentially i.e, first main window handle then child window handle will never be confirmed. That why it is working sometimes and some times not. It better to have main window handle and title in two separate variables like String mainWin = driver.getWindowHandle() and String mainWindowTitle = driver.getTitle() and while iterating just compare title to main window while switching to main window. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before clicking on login link get the parent window

   ```
   String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
   ```
2. Switch to your new window after clicking the login link (this is just one of the approaches)

   ```
    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
       driver.switchTo().window(handle);
   }
   ```
3. After finishing login, go back to your parent window

   ```
   driver.switchTo().window(secondWinHandle);
   ```

Comment: I tried this also, but did't worked. Could be a problem of waiting?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the logic used in the code. When you use: 
     Iterator it = handles.iterator();

the number of windows open is 2, so the conditional loop will be executed twice regardless of the the action performed within (I.e login and window closing automatically.

In the second iteration the parent window handle will be overwritten and the driver can't switch to it anymore.

In order to avoid this, you'll have to fetch and store your parent window handle either outside the loop or only once within. Code snippet with modification for the first solution is pasted below. Moving

```
String parent = it.next();
```

Outside the loop captures the parent window handle and retains the value.

```
Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
String parent = it.next(); 
// iterate through your windows
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String newwin = it.next();
    getDriver().switchTo().window(newwin);
    typeLoginCredentials
          (username,password);
     performClickOnLoginButton();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
 }
getDriver().switchTo().window(newwin);
loginShouldBeSuccessful();
```

Comment: I tried this also, but still, from time to time, after switching to parent window, the driver window is hanging, without doing anything. I tried to wait more than 5 seconds, but nothing. After loggin pop-up is closed automatically, the parent window loads a new URL. It is possible that the name that I stored initially to change after the new URL is loaded? (I mean this *String parent = it.next();*)

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown? If it's a matter of synchronization you may not want to use Thread.sleep. What you could also try is to fetch all window handles after the loop and switch to the first one. You could do a sysout of window handles before and after to see if there are any changes. If there aren't then it's a matter of synchronizing the script properly.

Comment: There is no exception thrown. I tried also to  fetch all windows after the loop but sometimes driver.getWindowHandles() gives no result. But when it works, there aren't any changes. Is there any other way to fix the syncronization, besides removing the Thread.sleep ?

Comment: There are a few things you could try..for instance after clicking on the button that opens the window, you can use a simple for loop to wait for the window handle count to be greater than 1. And to synchronize after the second window closes you can fetch window handles within another loop and wait for it to be 1. Normally using a Thread.sleep by itself is not a good approach.

Comment: I tried everything, nothing really works. This is definitely the weirdest thing that I found so far with Selenium. Thank you for your help anyway

Comment: Hmmm..all I can suggest at this point is if this works intermittently there's definitely something wrong with synchronization. Maybe you could use break points and run it step by step to see what's going on and modify your code based on findings. Good luck!